# Accessing undefined JSON attribute in javascript recursive function

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON structured like a tree: there is a root node and every node has some attributes and an array containing children nodes (node.children). I'm performing an in-order traversal with recursive calls i.e.

```
let myJsonTree = ...;
myFunction(myJsonTree.root);

function myFunction(node){
    for(let i=0; i<node.children.length; i++){
        myFunction(node.children[i]);   
    }
    ...
    doing something with node.attribute;
    ...
}
```

When I run this script locally in my IDE I don't get any errors, but when I run it on my Tomcat server I get the following error in the browser console: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attribute')".

What am I doing wrong ? Should I define in someway the node object (it's a subtree of the original JSON), or how can I access the attributes even if undefined ?

Comment: when that error appears, not `attributes` are undefined, but `node` itself. So there is no way to access the attributes when node does not exist

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you're trying to access properties on an object that is not properly defined.

Check it like this

```
if (node && node.attribute !== undefined) {
        console.log(node.attribute);
    }
```

or simply `node?.attribute`

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attribute')

Technically the code shown doesn't read a property called `attribute`, but implies it in this pseudo-comment:

```
doing something with node.attribute;
```

This implies that `node` itself is `undefined`.  `node` was supplied to the function:

```
function myFunction(node){
```

So, barring any upstream changes to *prevent* `undefined` nodes in the tree, you can handle them in a couple of ways.  Either use it as a return condition for the recursion:

```
function myFunction(node){
  if (!node) {
    return;
  }

  for(let i=0; i<node.children.length; i++){
    myFunction(node.children[i]);   
  }
  // doing something with node.attribute;
}
```

Or don't recurse on `undefined` values in the loop:

```
function myFunction(node){
  for(let i=0; i<node.children.length; i++){
    if (node.children[i]) {
      myFunction(node.children[i]);   
    }
  }
  // doing something with node.attribute;
}
```